# Replace all occurrences of a string no matter how different it written

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to see if this can be accomplished in plain and pure JavaScript.

Lets say I have a string :

```
var ourstring = "Blah TEST ('1')  TEST('2') Blah BLah TEST ( '1' )  TEST( '2' )";
```

Please pay attention to how different `TEST('1')` is written inside the string.

How can we detect all `TEST('')` inside the string no matter how different it written and replace them with something else based on the contain of the parenthesis.

So `TEST ('1')` become `TEST('1.node')` instead. Is that possible if yes, please show me and explain step by step so i can learn from it.

I have searched for such solution, but could not find anything. The problem I don't know how to do that. Please show me.

Comment: have you looked into regex? https://regexr.com/

Comment: Will definitely take look thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex `/(TEST)\s*\((\s*)'([\d]?)'(\s*)\)/g` captures five groups:

1. Word TEST
2. Spaces between TEST and the first `(`
3. Spaces between `'` and the inner number.
4. The inner number.
5. Spaces between `'` and the last `)`.

With those five groups, you can build the exact structure + the word `node`.

```js
var ourstring = "Blah TEST ('1')  TEST('2') Blah BLah TEST (      '1' )  TEST( '2'      )";
console.log(ourstring.replace(/(TEST)(\s*)\((\s*)'([\d])'(\s*)\)/g, "$1$2($3'$4.node'$5)"))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

This approach is for checking the captured group to make a decision about the desired value to be replaced.

```js
var ourstring = "Blah TEST ('1')  TEST('2') Blah BLah TEST (      '1' )  TEST( '2'      )";
console.log(ourstring.replace(/'([\d])'/g, function(match, group) {
  if (group === '1') {
    return `'${group}.nodeOne'`;
  }
  
  if (group === '2') {
    return `'${group}.nodeTwo'`;
  }
}))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Can you show me please how we can check parenthesis value inside if statement before the replace take place??

Comment: @HansHansen I don't understand, can you explain with an example?

Comment: Can we for loop all TEST()  so we can check the values inside the parenthesis before we replace??? if the value is 1 we can write somthing if the value is 2 we can write somthing else etc..

Comment: Alot of good anwser, but you were the first to understand me totally ! :) thank you and thanks to all other!

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression:

```js
    let str = "TEST ('1')  TEST('2') Blah BLah TEST ( '1' )  TEST( '2' )";
    const re = /TEST\s*\(\s*'([\d]*?)'\s*\)/g;
    str = str.replace(re, "TEST('$1.node')");
    console.log(str)
    /* str becomes:
       "TEST('1.node')  TEST('2.node') Blah BLah TEST('1.node')  TEST('2.node')"
    */
```

breaking down the regex step by step:

1. `TEST` to match the text exactly
2. `\s?` means optional whitespace; `\s` signifies any whitespace character, `?` signifies optional
3. `\(` to match parenthesis; it must be escaped since `(` relates to grouping in regular expressions
4. `([\d]*)` matches the characters between `[]` (in this case just digits, `\d`) 0-many times. Since it is between `()`, this value will be selected as a match group, and be available as `$1` in the replace string
5. `g` at the end is for greedy, meaning match as many times as possible in the given string

Depending on what you're going for, you way want to replace the optional (`?`) after whitespace with `*` to signify 0-many whitespace characters.

Comment: Can you break down the regex? Eg: explain it part by part. Looks like Hans hasn't heard of it before

Comment: he's been faster (:. see https://regex101.com/r/qAegBW/2, you have full explanations on the right panel

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway we can check parenthesis value inside if statement before the replace take place??

Comment: @HansHansen yes, just use str.match instead of replace. See documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: @treyhakanson Thank you very much for the explanation and example!! i tried to that:  str = str.match(re, "TEST('$1.node')"); but it removes all other words "Blah", can you show me how please??

Comment: You don't need the square brackets to create a character class, since `\d` is already a character class. `([\d]*)` is the same as `(\d*)`

Comment: @StephenP I included square braces incase he wanted to check for multiple types of characters (see the explaination)

Comment: @HansHansen, if removed all other words "blah", it should be caused by something is wrong with your regex expression, you need to post out your regex expression for toubleshooting.

Comment: I used the same code, just changed replace with match as pointed out by treyhakanson

Comment: @HansHansen, check this [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), then you will find out the differences between match and replace.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a regex replace. You need to write a regular expression which will match the text that you want to change and then use it with `String.replace`.

```
var newString = ourString.replace(/(TEST\('\d+)('\))/gi, function(match, group1, group2) {
   return group1+'.node'+group2;
});
```

The important part of that is the regex:
    (TEST('\d+)('))

This matches the TEST followed by brackets, quotes and one or more digits, then closing quotes and brackets.
It puts the first part (e.g. `TEST('1`) into a capturing group and then does the same with the second part (`')`).

These should end up in the `group1` and `group2` variables.
Then the function is just stitching these back together again with your extra `.node` in the middle.

**edit**

You could just capture the number and then decide what to return based on that:

```
var newString = ourString.replace(/TEST\('(\d+)'\)/gi, function(match, num) {
   if(num == '1')
        return "TEST('1.node')";
   else
        return "TEST('1.otherThing')";
});
```

The thing to look at in the regex is that there are literal brackets which match what is in your string `\(` and there are capturing groups (which are the unescaped brackets).

Comment: Can we check each TEST() value inside the parenthesis before doing the replace?? so we can replace the with different text acording to the value??

Comment: Yes, you could capture the number separately and then do some logic using it to decide what you wanted to return. If the number is the only important part then you could just capture that.

Comment: Can you please show me how that is done??? i'm trying to see how to understand it... - the number is not only the important part, the whole string is important